# How to insert data with specific ID into Postgres using Sequel

Tags: ruby, database, postgresql, sequel

I'm populating a Postgres database using the Sequel gem. However, the data is pulled from another DB and already contains an ID. I'm only pulling a very small subsection of those ID's, and they are completely random, so they are very much out of order.

Is it possible to insert items into my database and provide the specific ID to use as a primary key, or is that a bad idea? I tried to provide the ID manually  and got "id is a restricted primary key".

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". It'd help others in the future if you provide more detail about what you're doing and how you're doing it. The minimal code that demonstrates the problem is helpful; Code, like a picture, is worth 10,000 words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't insert the id, because the database and Sequel want to define the primary index value as a sequential number.

You can remove the `:id` from the hash using Hash's `delete` method:

```
foo = {id: 1, bar: 2}
foo.delete(:id) # => 1
foo # => {:bar=>2}
```

then use [`insert`](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/cheat_sheet_rdoc.html#label-Insert+rows).

If you absolutely *must* reuse those IDs, then you could sort your data by the primary IDs, then loop over the records, inserting dummy records for the gaps and then the real data, allowing the DBM to use the next sequential number still. But that's really going against the flow of how we use a DB.

Comment: Fair enough - I decided to store the existing ID as 'originalID', which works. Thank you!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using camelCase names for fields. Stick with snake_case, which will then work well once you're using Sequel's models. (You should do that as they're extremely powerful.)